# Ubuntu not showing up in windows 7 network

Tags: 12.04, windows, synergy

[image]

I have a windows 7 laptop and ubuntu desktop, and both are connected to the same network, I can see the windows laptop in ubuntu's network, also I can access it, copy past files,on windows I cannot see ubuntu in the network. I want to use synergy and use ubuntu as server, I've done all the configuration.

Desktop ip is 192.168.0.101
when I enter '\\192.168.0.101' in run in windows, It says it cannot find the network path, and synergy gives a timeout error.
I know the issue seems to be with windows, hope I can get some support here.

This setup(sharing and synergy) has worked with 10.10 now I'm using 12.04.

Comment: Synergy must work without any modifications, so I assume you have the wrong internal ip address. For file sharing, you should install Samba, without you cant access a windows network.(you said you could share files already?)

Comment: thanks but samba is already installed,as I said I can view all contents of my laptop(win7) from ubuntu. how can I solve wrong ip address issue? I'm succesfully able to ping win7 from ubuntu i.e. i wrote ping 192.168.0.102(laptop's ip)on ubuntu , when I do this on laptop 'ping 192.168.0.101(ubuntu's ip) I get only 4 packets and it ends.

Comment: enter ifconfig on the ubuntu host to find the internal ip, use ipconfig on windows to find the internal ip, check if that matches your given ips. it really sounds like you got the wrong ip for ubuntu.

Comment: do you have a homegroup initialized on the windows 7 computer ?
i remember having problems similar to yours.. and it was because of homegroup being initialized..  and something about user authentification (ACL) using different encryption grades.. but that part is somewhat cloudy at the moment.. after some sleep i might remember :)

Comment: I've added the image for both windows and ubuntu ip/ifconfig, yes windows is connected to homegroup, Please let me know if anything click when you wake up.